# Testing of function inside custom react hook (Jest and react testing library)

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm in the process of figuring out how to test a function in a custom hook.

Here is the custom hook:

**useOpenTab.tsx:**

```js
import { useRouteParams } from "hooks";

import { useOpenTabMutation } from "state/modules/tab/api";

type FilteredData = any;

export function useOpenTab() {
  const { assetId } = useRouteParams();
  const [openTabAction] = useOpenTabMutation();

  const openItems = (filteredData: FilteredData[]) => {
    const data = filteredData.reduce((acc, item) => {
      if (
        acc.find(
          (order) =>
            order.id === item.id &&
            order.tag === item.location
        )
      ) {
        return acc;
      }
      acc.push({ id: item.number, tag: item.location });
      return acc;
    }, [] as { id: string; tag: string }[]);
    
    openTabAction({ assetId, data }); // the api call, I need to find out what the "data" is
  };
  return openItems;
}
```

I do not wish to refactor the custom hook in order to make it easier to test. As seen in the comment in the code, I wish to find out what the `data` property after the reduce has run. I therefore wish to "spy" on the arguments of the `openTabAction` function, which is a rtk query (what this function is/does is irrelevant I believe).

My attempt at writing the test goes like this:

**openTab.test.ts**

```js
import { renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-named-as-default
import { useRouteParams } from "hooks";
import * as useCustomHook from "../useOpenTab";
import { mockedData } from "./mockedData";


const resultAfterFunction = [
  {
    id: "1",
    tag: "1",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    tag: "2",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    tag: "3",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    tag: "4",
  },
];

// Mocking Selector hooks
jest.mock("hooks");
const useRouteParamsMock = useRouteParams as jest.Mock;
const openItemsMock = jest.fn();

jest
  .spyOn(useCustomHook, "useOpenTab")
  .mockImplementation(() => {
    return openItemsMock; // mocking the openItems function
  });


describe("data param of action should be correct", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    // mocking the useParams hook
    useRouteParamsMock.mockClear();
    useRouteParamsMock.mockReturnValueOnce({ assetId: 1 });
  });

  it("should return an array with object inside", async () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() =>
      useCustomHook.useOpenTab()
    );
    const openItems = result.current;
    openItems(mockedData);
    expect(openItemsMock).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({
      id: 1,
      data: resultAfterFunction,
    });

  });
});
```

**Questions:**

1. Is what I have up until this point correct?
2. How do I now spy on the function `openTabAction` and see what the `data` argument equals? Thanks:)
3. I'm getting an error on the .spy call:

33 | jest
> 34 |   .spyOn(useCustomHook, "useOpenTab")

TypeError: Cannot redefine property: useOpenTab
at Function.defineProperty ()

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have written is mostly correct. Except that you don't want to spy on `useOpenTab` this is the function you want to test and you are explicitly calling it here:

```
    const { result } = renderHook(() =>
      useCustomHook.useOpenTab()
    );
```

So you can see that it is called without any arguments.

You want to see how `openTabAction` is called, which is returned by `useOpenTabMutation()`, so that is what you want to mock, at the top of your testfile:

```
import * apiModule from "state/modules/tab/api";

const mockOpenTabAction = jest.fn();
jest.spyOn(apiModule,'useOpenTabMutation')
  .mockReturnValue(mockOpenTabAction);
```

and in your test:

```
    expect(mockOpenTabAction).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith({
      //the mockData you expect
    });
```

I think it should look something like this. The tricky thing is that you mock a hook that returns a spy (I did it with spyOn, but you can also do it with mock). That feels a bit weird but the action you actually want to spy on is returned by the hook, so this is the way to go.
This is how I do it for all the post calls to RTK query, which have the same structure.